# MPMoviePlayerController and let the user replay

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an iOS app with a MPMoviePlayerController, I need to play a video from an URL. Everything seems to work fine, but when the playback ends the MPMoviePlayerController shows a weird image and it takes AGES to replay the video...

This is what I have so far:

```
mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And the moviePlayerLoadStateChanged and moviePlayBackDidFinish look like this:

```
- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([mp loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                              object:nil];

        [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
        [mp setFullscreen:NO];
        [mp.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 54, 300, 200)];
        [mp setShouldAutoplay:NO];
        [mp prepareToPlay];

        [[self view] addSubview:[self.mp view]];
    }   
}
```

I don't know what that Image is, but I would like to replace it... also I think it takes so much because it's loading the video from a URL, I don't know how to add a loading, or a spinner... Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `repeatMode` property of your `MPMoviePlayerController` to `MPMovieRepeatModeOne`

**by using:**

```
mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
          initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];///Put your path to your resource
mp.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

I hope this helps if i understood your question correctly.
If not i recommend checking out the documentation [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html)

Happy coding:)